# Radon-Nikodym Derivative with respect to counting measure

Tags: real-analysis

This comes from Exercise $1.2.4$ of Tao's $\textit{An Epsilon of Room}$:

Let $X$ be an at most countable set with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra. Show that every measure on $X$ is differentiable with respect to the counting measure (denoted $\#$).

My attempt at a solution is to try to switch the order of integration. Note that I'm using that $\int_{\{ x \} } d \# = 1$ below. Let $A \subset X$, and $\mu$ a measure $\mu : 2^X \to [0, \infty]$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_A d \mu &= \int_A \int_{ \{ x \} } d \# d \mu \\
&= \int_{ \{ x \} } \int_A d \mu d \# \quad \textrm{(Fubini's)} \\
&= \sum_{x \in A} \int_{ \{ x \} } \int_{ \{ x \} } d \mu d \# \\
&= \int_A  \int_{ \{ x \} } d \mu d \# \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Hence, we can take $f(x) := \mu ( \{ x \} )$ as our Radon-Nikodym derivative. I am not fully confident in this solution as I don't know if my "transfer" of the sum on the last two lines of the above is justified. Is this on the right track?

Comment: Seems good to me.As regards interchange sum and integral There's a question in this forum 'when can a sum and integral be interchanged ?'. Sorry I can't provide  the link I'm on tablet.

Comment: I am confused; isn't the counting measure non-zero on any non-empty subset and so absolute continuity is vacuously satisfied on nonempty subsets and trivially satisfied on the empty set?